# how to close print dialog when user cancel print preview dialog

Tags: c#-4.0, printing

I need some help. 
My requirement is when the user click on print button it should show a print preview dialog.
if user cancel or close the preview dialog the form must be return to original.

the problem i am facing is print preview dialog box is visible. but i don't know how to capture the print preview tools click events.

```
public void print()
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        PaperSize psize = new PaperSize(); 
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
        pd.Document = pdoc;
        pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;

        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);

         DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
         if (result == DialogResult.OK)
         {

             PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
             ppd.Document = pdoc;
             ppd.ShowDialog();

             pdoc.Print();
         }
    }
```

if i place the PrintPreviewDialog  code before pd.ShowDialog() nothing visible in the preview mode.
this not working

```
            PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        ppd.Document = pdoc;
        ppd.ShowDialog();
         DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
         if (result == DialogResult.OK)
         {  
             pdoc.Print();
         }
```

Comment: Click the Print toolbar button in the dialog to get a printout.  If you don't like the way it works then make your own dialog with PrintPreviewControl.

Comment: after printing its shows the print dialog again,since pdoc.Print(); is executing

Answer (score 0):

DialogResult is not supported in showdialog() with print dialog .

so the worked way is true or false

```
 PrintDialog pri = new PrintDialog();
                         if (pri.ShowDialog() == true)
                        {
                            pri.PrintQueue.AddJob(fileName, fileName,false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;   
                        }
```

you can also not to use pri.ShowDialog() as the if statement already invoking the method also .

Comment: Your answer seems to apply to `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog`. Based on Jinesh's use of the `Document` property, I believe they're using `System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog`.